# NSFetchedResultsController new section after update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have background thread which updates the entity and I have tableView which shows this entity simultaneously. TableView is empty at the beginning and should be filled with upcoming data asynchronously. Obviously, with first insertion I increase the count of sections as well. Eventually, I get the following message: *CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo*

```
lazy var _result_controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Channel> =
{
    let app_delegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Channel> = Channel.fetchRequest();
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "frame", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)];

    let retval: NSFetchedResultsController<Channel> = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                                                 managedObjectContext: app_delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext,
                                                                                 sectionNameKeyPath: "frame",
                                                                                 cacheName: nil);
    retval.delegate = self;

    self.tableView?.reloadData();

    return retval;

}();

var _block: Array<BlockOperation> = Array<BlockOperation>();

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try _result_controller.performFetch();
    } catch let error {
        print(error);
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
{
    switch(type) {
    case .insert:
        self._block.append(BlockOperation(block: {
                                                    self.tableView?.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .bottom);
                                                    }
        ));
        // self.tableView?.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true);
        break;
    case .update:
        self._block.append(BlockOperation(block: {
                                                    self.tableView?.reloadRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .bottom);
                                                    }
        ));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
{
    self.tableView?.beginUpdates();
    for operation in self._block {
        operation.start();
    }
    self.tableView?.endUpdates();

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return self._result_controller.sections?.count ?? 0;
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if let count = self._result_controller.sections?[section].numberOfObjects {
        return count;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD1**
As @pbsdf advised:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
{
    switch (type) {
    case .insert:
        self.tableView?.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom);
        break;
    case .delete:
        self.tableView?.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, I'm getting similar error message:
*Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)*

Comment: Looks like you need to implement [controller(_:didChange:atSectionIndex:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/1622298-controller).

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks! Sounds reasonable, but stack with another error — have a glance please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with BlockOperations, but I suspect the problem is that the `insertSections` needs to be added as a block operation, and executed with the other updates, rather than being executed directly.  Any particular reason for using block operations?